# Incorrect Polygon Area Calculations in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geometry, area

I have converted a raster to a polygon, dissolved the polygons into singlepart, and tried to calculate areas using Calculate Geometry. Many of the areas are 'zero' or are areas that are obviously not correct.

How can I fix this?

When I calculate the areas for the undissolved polygons they appear to be correct. They are just subdivided into grid cells with the same spatial resolution as the Landsat image from which they are derived (30m x 30m). So, one grid cell has an area of 900 sq meters. The problem is that I need the grid cells dissolved so I can determine the exact number of polygons and their respective areas, hence the use of the dissolve tool.

The defined projection is WGS UTM Zone 9N (the same as the Landsat image) and it has never been changed.

Comment: Try repair geometry http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003v000000.. the area calculation fails on non-simple geometries which could be why you're having problems. If that doesn't help calculate the areas in the undissolved polygons then dissolve http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000 with a sum of area field.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your reply. Repair geometry does not seem to make a difference. I calculated areas for the undissolved polygons, then dissolved by the Area Field sum as you suggested, but it just assigns the sum of all of the areas to all of the polygons (so, they all have exactly the same area). Thoughts?

Comment: Did you specify your *dissolve field* so that not all polygons were made into one polygon? I'm assuming you have polygons with different values that you want to maintain but as an aggregate area of the same values.

Comment: I did not specify any dissolve field, just the Statistic Field with Area as the chosen field and Sum as the chosen statistic. This results in separate polygons (as desired), but all with the same value for Area (which is not correct).

Comment: Would it help for you to see the shapefiles? I can provide them.

Comment: Yes, and an idea of what you intend to achieve as a final result from this step of your process.

Comment: Okay great, I can do that. How can I send the files to you (my apologies, I am new here)? I can zip them but I am not sure how to attach them here.

Comment: It's not normal so I don't think there's a standard procedure.. zip them and put them on Google Drive, dropbox or whatever cloud storage you use and share the link. Make sure that there isn't a login required; some cloud storage requires a login or signup which makes it difficult.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1S9-Yudm3Q5ELE4mgUQ6WM73EHCrK_fBF?usp=sharing

Comment: Let me know if that link works. I didn't zip them, they aren't that large. 'Icings_2_clip' is the product of the raster to polygon conversion, but the dissolve hasn't been performed. 'dissolve_test' is where I tried to dissolve by the Area Sum. Essentially, I want all of the grid cells from 'Icings_2_clip' to be joined IF they are touching. All grid cells which are touching should be aggregated into one polygon. Then, I want to know the area of those aggregated polygons.

Comment: I see, that's a dissolve with no multipart, but the result appears to all be the same area: 35135607. Are you trying to get the actual area of each merged polygon or the number of 30m cells X area of a single cell (90 sq.m.). I did a repair geometry on dissolve_text and calculated the geometry and got some reasonable values https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n__COC1o8-tAfzfZ3E308uEBw0IoSv1-

Comment: I am trying to calculate the exact area of each merged polygon, although the pixel count of each polygon would serve the same purpose. Either would work. Heading into the office now so I'll take a look at your shapefile. Strange that the repair geometry seems to have worked for you but would not work for me.

Comment: Michael - I have replicated what you did and it seems to work fine now even without repair geometry. I wasn't recalculating the areas after I dissolved by the sum, but as soon as I did that I ended up with the same values as you did, which seem to be correct. Thank you SO much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I cannot comment, so will add an answer.
I downloaded your information, and have seen your initial data and your dissolve.
Can I ask why you do not recalculate the areas of your dissolved polygons after the dissolve?

Create a field called dissolved area and run the "Calculate Geometry" on that field by right-clicking and selecting it from the context window that appears.

If I have missed the boat, I apologise and will delete this answer.

Comment: Hi Keagan, This is what I tried to do initially but the geometries calculated after the dissolve were not correct, hence my post here. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I downloaded the data as well and I have to agree with Keagan, the Calculate Geometry is giving accurate results, they might just be unexpected results. A couple things to try- did you use the Simplify Polygons option in the Raster to Polygon tool? Also, your area field is a Long, try making it a Float and you will see that the polygons with 0 area are being rounded down

Comment: Yes I've gotten it sorted out now. The issue was that I was not dissolving the correct field. Now, once I dissolve by the Area Sum I can just recalculate the geometries and they are correct. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BrittneyG. glad it worked out!